# AWS Lambda cannot get access token from Google Drive

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, google-drive-api

I have to get access_token to upload file to google drive.
My code running fine in local, but after I deploy it to lambda and run, it's failed with timed out error.

My get access_token code:

```
def get_access_token():
r = requests.post(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    headers={'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    data={
        'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
        'client_id': gdrive_client_id,
        'client_secret': gdrive_client_secret,
        'refresh_token': gdrive_refresh_token
    }
)
r.raise_for_status()
result = r.json()
return result["access_token"]
```

Can you tell me what went wrong and how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. Look at the indentation. Also you should post SOMETHING from your cloudwatch logs. A mistyped snippet of code isn't enough to go on.

Comment: **1.** Solve your indentation problems and try again (sometimes when you deploy these mistakes happen). **2.** Are you using the credentials.json file in your local machine and/or in the lambda instance? **3.** Could you please share the full description of the error logged?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf yes, I'm using credentials.json file in your local machine and in the lambda instance.. also to read/write into "token" folder, I am using "/tmp" folder.
But I am getting error for redirecting url.. it's working properly on my local machine but it's giving me error while running aws lambda function. and redirect_uri I'm using is: http://localhost:8888/Callback
please help me to resolve it!
Thanks.